# Converting characters to UTF-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, junit

In my unit test, i'm trying to prove that HTTP Responses sent onto client applications only contain valid UTF-8 characters.  This is off the back of an issue whereby the British Pound symbol '£' was not sent as a UTF-8 encoded character, causing a validation failure for a client application.

In my test i'm doing the following:

```
// setup
byte[] outputData = "£".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String serviceXmlResponse = String.format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><some>%s</some>", outputData.toString());
String expectedXmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><some>£</some>";
when(service.getMessage()).thenReturn(serviceXmlResponse);

// act
ModelAndView result = controller.handlePostRequest(request, response, mav);

// assert
assertEquals(expectedXmlContent, result.getModel().get(ApplicationController.RESPONSE_KEY));
```

The resultant XML contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><some>[B@1164b9b6</some>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Calling `.toString()` on a byte array doesn't do what you think it does. Why are you converting the `£` to a byte array, anyway?

Comment: This was the symbol causing an issue, presumably due to native i.e. ISO8859-1 encoding on the machine hosting the application.  The application is essentially middleware, acting as a proxy between services.

Answer (score 2):

If `service.getMessage()` returns your XML as a `String`, whereas `result.getModel().get(ApplicationController.RESPONSE_KEY)` returns the same XML in encoded form as a `byte[]`, your test should look like this:

```
String serviceXmlResponse = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><some>£</some>";
when(service.getMessage()).thenReturn(serviceXmlResponse);

assertArrayEquals(serviceXmlResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"), (byte[]) result.getModel().get(ApplicationController.RESPONSE_KEY));
```

Otherwise your test doesn't make much sense, especially if `result.getModel().get(ApplicationController.RESPONSE_KEY)` returns a `String`, so that actual encoding is applied in the view, after generating model attributes.

**See also:**

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 1):

`[B` is what you get when you call `toString()` on a `byte` array.

So your test doesn't work since it basically says: "Return the expected output when `getMessage()` is called". So it tests `assertEquals (expected, expected);`

Your problem is in the code which reads the XML bytes from the socket and then converts them into a String that is returned by `service.getMessage()`

So your code must look like:

```
String expectedXmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><some>£</some>";
byte[] data = expectedXmlContent.getBytes("UTF-8");

... send data to service as byte stream ...

assertEquals(expectedXmlContent, service.getMessage());
```

Also don't mix encodings; if the XML says "UTF-8", then you must use the same encoding in `getBytes()`.

Comment: The service provider sends XML to our client that has the XML heading that you see above i.e. <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"> BUT the contents are actually encoded as ISO-8859-1.  Our code is trying to make sure that it converts the XML contents into UTF-8.  The unit test is trying to prove that our code does this.

Comment: I understand; but your test already does the ISO-8859-1 -> UTF-8 conversion *outside* of the service. You really need to feed the ISO-Latin-1 bytes to the service (instead of a Unicode string) to see whether it can convert them or not.